# data.table : `get` of a non existing column to existing column fails silently

Tags: r, data.table

```
    > d <- data.table(x = 1:5)
    > d[x == 6, y := get("i_9")]
    Error in get("i_9") : object 'i_9' not found

    > d[, y := 1]   # add a new column y
    > d[x == 6, y := get("i_9")]
    <No Error>
```

`get` of non existing column `i_9` to:

a. non existent column `y` fails 
b. existent column `y` fails silently

How do we justify this behavior.

Comment: For the first part [see your (almost) duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66871033/10782538). For the latter I would ask the Rdatatable team on github. It seems similar to exhibit similar behaviour to `tapply(numeric(), numeric(), get('i_9'))`, eg. assignment by group, and since there are 0 groups it does not actually evaluate. Edge case because `y` exists (in contrary to not exist). It seems like an "edge" of potentially unintended behaviour.

Comment: Done : https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4948. Thanks Oliver !