# Why should `get` for non existent column throw an error if condition is not satisfied?

Tags: r, data.table

```
d <- data.table(x = 1:5)
d[x == 6, p := get("non_existing_column")]
Error in get("non_existing_column") : 
  object 'non_existing_column' not found
```

Since the condition `x == 6` is not satisfied for any row, why should `data.table` throw an error ?

Comment: My guess is that `data.table` implements some checks to ensure that the operations on `j` (i.e., the `get("non_existing_column")`) 'make sense' before performing the subsetting.

Answer (score 4):

`get` is not a function from the `data.table` package. Using it within `[.data.table` is usually a method for abusing stored variable names. Eg:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
x <- 'cyl'
mtcars[, get(x)]
```

The reason this works is that `data.table` evaluated the expression within a "child-environment" of the specific `data.table` which has the global environment as the `parent.frame`. Meaning it will first "look for `x` within `mtcars`. If it isn't there it will look for it within the next frame (here the `globalenv()`, but it could also be a function environment). It then forces `x`, and evaluates `get(force(x)) = get("cyl")` (in spirit).

Next `get` tries to find the variable `cyl`. Since it is evaluated within the environment of the `data.table` ( here `mtcars` ), the name exists and the vector of values is returned, note that this is **not** the `data.table` column. It returns `mtcars$cyl`, not `mtcars[, .(cyl)]`

Now if the variable stored in `x` was **not** in the `data.table` environment, `get` will then search the `parent.frame` of this environment ( once again this is the `globalenv()` in our example ) and since it can't find it, `get` throws an error.

This is exactly equivalent to doing

```
d <- list2env(mtcars)
get("non_existing_column", envir = d)
```

## Conclusion

What you're seeing is not `data.table` throwing an error, but `get("non_existing_column")`, because it can't find the variable anywhere.

Comment: So, the question is why was the `j` evaluated in the `data.table`, despite the condition being always false ?

Comment: That question is actually simple. `data.table(x = 1:5)[x == 6]` returns an empty `data.table` (0 rows) with 1 column `x`. In practice if your code is in production to perform data transformation work, it is a lot less likely to break if it gets a `data.table` with the correct column of length 0, compared to the situation where -if no rows are returned- `NULL` is returned (for example).

Comment: basically I'd rather want `mtcars[0, cyl]` to return a `data.table` compared to any alternative. And that requires `j` to be evaluated. That is the ideom used in `data.table` and `data.frame` alike.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but why would we evaluate `j` when condition is of length 0. We could have simply assigned a column with length 0. I suppose that's because we want to keep it simple and we do not wish to add more checks (ifs) in computation

Comment: a related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868210/data-table-get-of-a-non-existing-column-to-existing-column-fails-silently. Your inputs will surely help...

Comment: For the prior, you'd have to ask yourself if this would be consistent behaviour. What should be returned? A column? Which column? Without evaluating `j` you wouldn't know the column. If you're using `get` inside the call, it is void, because it is handled not by the `data.table` engine, but by `get` itself, and the question becomes even more inconsistent in the case of multiple columns `mget(c("x", "y"))`.